# How do Manotaurs reproduce?

Tags: gravity-falls

In the *Gravity Falls* episode "Dipper vs. Manliness", Dipper meets a tribe of manotaurs.

How could a species of such manly individuals possibly reproduce?

Comment: There's no answer in-universe. Maybe they just bud off of Leader-er?

Comment: Or perhaps there's a population of Womanotaurs elsewhere that we've just not seen yet?

Answer (score 8):

As it happens, the concept of a 'manotaur' isn't unique to *Gravity Falls*. The first appearance of such a creature pre-dates the show by nearly two decades, from the [*Advanced Dungeons and Dragons 2nd edition : Monstrous Compendium Annual (Volume III)*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Annual-Monstrous-Compendium-Advanced-Dungeons/dp/0786904496). Whether this is the ***direct*** inspiration for the manotaurs seen in the TV show isn't clear but the genesis seems pretty similar - a manotaur is a reversed minotaur.

The book even provides a picture and description (see below) that seems remarkably similar, as well as an educated guess on their breeding habits;

> *A manotaur somewhat resembles a centaur. Unlike a minotaur, which has the body of a man and the head of a bull, a manotaur has the body of a bull and the upper torso of a man. The head sports a pair of horns that a manotaur continually sharpens for use in combat. A great mane of hair runs down its neck, trailing across its shoulders. Coloration varies, but most manotaurs are brown, gray or black. Manotaurs measure seven to eight feet tall and ten to 12 feet in length. The human torso is broad and powerful. Manotaurs are strict carnivores; their mouths are wide and filled with sharpened teeth and short fangs.*
>
> *The origins of the first manotaur are a mystery; **possibly it was the offspring of a minotaur and a human female.** Manotaurs live 300 years or more.*

[image: picture of a Manotaur and the species's main characteristics: body of a bull, torso of a man, head half of both. He looks angry.]